# Why is Parse is not defined?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Parse closed down today, and my whole web application broke. I migrated to my own server and database, but all I am seeing is `parse is not defined` on both my server and client side.

```
"dependencies": {
    "parse": "~1.8.0",
    "parse-server": "~2.2.12",
  }
```

This is how I instantiate the require statement for parse

```
var Parse = require('parse/node');
Parse.initialize(process.env.APP_ID, process.env.JAVASCRIPT_KEY, process.env.MASTER_KEY);
Parse.serverURL = process.env.SERVER_URL;
```

Client side:

```
https://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.6.12.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: `Why is Parse is not defined?` ... well `Parse closed down today` ... and `the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` - pretty self evident

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but I thought when they put everything on github, you could still make calls to your own database using the same syntax.

Comment: Your code is still referencing the CDN which presumably they took down, if you have installed locally via NPM you can just reference that version directly

Comment: what code is making the request in the browser?

Comment: I am running a script tag with the parsecdn. I used angular to make my webapp which is why I need to reference the cdn

Answer (score 2):

The error produced suggests that there is something in the application that is referencing an older version of parse. Your dependencies lists 1.8.0, but there error is referencing 1.6.12

There is something else in your app trying to get those files. Check your html file for something requesting this, or just do a search on parsecdn.com

Comment: How come I never had this issue? I have cron jobs running on my server which are independent of the client side, and I installed through npm on my server, and I am still getting the error